# what is going on with my phone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s

recently my phone has started installing invisible apps without my permission.
I have three different security programs, and at random times they will pop up in the notification bar with " scanning installed app ". even though I didn't tell it t do that.
at the end, there is no actual app there, so wtf installed?

I'm not sure if it's some virus installing invisible apps, or if it is Google performing unpermissive updates, but I have told Google I do not want it to auto update and it's trying to do it anyway.

I know that whatever this is, it has something to do with Google Play because. have a firewall.
I have told my firewall to block anything from the google services framework and as long as the firewall is on it won't do this.
however, if I turn off the firewall, it goes nuts. trying to auto update, and install all kinds of unwanted garbage.
what can I do? can I just uninstall play store?

Samsung Sch- i110 * rooted
2.36 Gingerbread

Avast! mobile security * firewall
Malwarebytes Anti- malware

Comment: Could it be that it is scanning already installed apps rather than a newly installed app? I expect this is more likely than invisible apps being installed on your phone. Do the notifications happen at regular intervals or the same time each day?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be uninstalling those unesecary security programs, seeing if the problem persisits, in my experience android security programs are both unesecary and cause more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need all those crap of security apps, I've been using android for several years without such issues. I'd suggest you backup your data and perform a factory reset, that will make your phone pretty fast and new like. And avoid installing such bloatware (even 1 is too much, you are coping with 3). They also affect your battery life. Just one thing you can do to protect your phone is go to settings>security, uncheck "unknown sources" and you should be fine.. for now a factory reset is required i guess.. just to be safe.